# Call by value for classes c++ design decision

Tags: c++

I wonder why C++ uses 'call by value' for classes as default? I imagine this could have advantages in the sense of performance (speed). I mean C# and Java pass classes as references as default.

What are the reasons why C++ pass classes as copies as default?

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: Java and C# are also call-by-value by default. It just happens that you can only ever get a pointer/reference to a `class`-type, and that's what's passed.

Answer (score 7):

You are labouring under a misconception:
**Java and C are always pass-by-value, C# and C++ only by default.**
(C# has `out` and `ref` arguments, C++ has references.)

The difference between C++ and Java/C# is that in the latter two you can only ever get a pointer (called reference) to a `class`-type (or any other so-called reference-type, and only to those).

And why is it the default respective only way *by value*?
Consistency, safety and simplicity. It's the simplest way and reduces unintended modification of the arguments.
Anyway, it's as easy to emulate *pass-by-reference* (or add syntax to do it) starting from that point, as it is to emulate *pass-by-value* the other way around.

Answer (score 4):

For C++, the answer is simple: Classes are `struct`s (or the other way round), and `struct`s are passed by value because they are passed by value in C. This ensures that a usable subset of C can be compiled as C++ code.

---

For C, it's not that straight-forward. But C has the unique feature that it does not have implicit references. Anything that would use an implicit reference in other languages uses an explicit pointer in C. (The only implicit thing about pointers in C is the implicit decay of arrays and function names to pointers.)

This explicit-pointer feature has two beneficial effects:

1. It helps to keep the language simple.

   If you have implicit references, you have at the very least to differentiate between the creation of a reference and an assignment of the data behind that reference, like C++ does. Or you have to make the objects themselves unassignable like Java does. Or you have to have special syntax to assign the reference like Fortran does.

   Either way adds significant complexity to the language and the compiler on top of the explicit pointer scheme. Yet, those explicit pointers allow you to do anything other languages do with implicit references by just adding an occasional `*` or `&`, or swapping a `->` for a `.`.
2. It eases reasoning about what memory a function call can touch. When you see a call like `foo(myStruct)`, you know that `foo()` cannot change `myStruct` without even looking at the declaration of `foo()`. On the other hand, `foo(&myStruct)` gives a strong signal that `myStruct` will not be the same after the call.

   I consider C++ references as a step back in this regard.

On the performance consideration: It is impossible to say that either pass-by-value or pass-by-reference is faster in general. The truth is, that pass-by-value is faster for simple types, and pass-by-reference is faster for complex types.

The designers of C must have known that most `struct`s would be faster with pass-by-reference. I believe that they went for an all-pass-by-value language anyway because they felt that passing implicit references is detrimental to language simplicity with doubtful effects on its usability.

Comment: @5gon12eder That's what I meant by language simplicity. Maybe I should elaborate more on that point, to make it clearer.

Comment: @5gon12eder Nevertheless, I have elaborated a bit more about the meaning of "language simplicity" in point 1, now. I hope it makes the point clearer to the casual reader :-)

Comment: Is the existence of references a step backwards? Well, it depends on how you look at it: While they were introduced for operator-overloading, strictly speaking one could have introduced that using pointers, though with restrictions: How do you signal that a copy must be passed (or a C++11 rvalue-reference) then? Those same difficulties and more exist when writing widely useful templates, or types you want to use with them... For comparison, C# only has myopic generics, and needs a ref/out  qualifier as part of both callsite and declaration. Such a mandatory difference would kill templates...

Comment: Mutability and referencing are fairly orthogonal really. And there's more than one way to skin a cat - in `x += y` nobody expects `x` to be the same after it.

Comment: @DeadMG Of course, when the function is `operator +=`. But, even though you would never expect `y` to change, C++ definitely allows you to write an `operator +=` that does change `y`. These nasty surprises make me dislike non-const references in C++. Operator overloading is another dangerous tool in that regard: You can't tell what an expression actually does until you have looked up all the involved operators. Don't get me wrong: Operator overloading has its uses (smart pointers!), but with great power comes great responsibility to *not* use it in all the ways that look cool at first glance.

Answer (score 1):

By far the most important reason why it is done this way is for consistency.

This is how everything else is passed, so why not structs and classes too?

One major justification for sticking with this consistency is that in C and C++ you have to always be mindful of indirections, (and how many of them a given variable represents,) so the general approach taken by the language is to avoid hiding indirections from the programmer. This way, everything which is not adorned with a '&' is passed by value, unless the function itself declares the argument to be a reference, in which case you do not need to supply the '&' when you are calling, and instead you have to remember that there is a '&' in the receiving end.  (But you have made this choice, so you have brought this additional mental burden upon yourself.)

Another justification is that if structs and classes were to be an exception to the rule of passing everything by value, then the language would still have to give you a way to specify that you do in fact want an occasional struct/class to be passed by value, and then what ugly modifications would the syntax of the language have to undergo in order to facilitate this?  The language already has syntax for taking a reference of something, but not for passing the value of something.

Please note: my C++ might be a bit rusty, so I may have made some small mistake or used a somewhat wrong word for something. If you know better, that's entirely possible, but instead of downvoting, please modify the answer to fix that minor mistake.